# Silverlight How to read a directory locally

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am new to Silverlight and I am trying to do a directory listing of the contents of a directory. However when the first list of this code runs, it throws an exception:

The application itself runs inside of a Browser.

> File operation not permitted. Access
>   to path 'C:\Program Files\AppName' is
>   denied.

I checked permissions and they are readable so I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\AppName");

    try
    {
        if (di.Exists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
    finally { }
```

Comment: Assuming you run this inside of a browser, you may have just hit the walls of the sandbox. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight doesn't let you just access any old directory you want. Silverlight 4 added the ability to access certain well-known paths under the user profile but only in out-of-browser elevated trust applications.

Silverlight is probably not the technology you want to use for this purpose. Look into WPF instead.

Comment: The application itself is Silverlight and I dont think I can just throw in some WPF calls since it's sandboxed as you said in Silverlight. Is there any other way to get it to work?

Comment: If there was then silverlight would be one mighty bad ria platform (what you want to do has large security implications)

Comment: @Matt && @Josh: Thanks for insight on Silverlight. Yes I agree with the security implications. I think I will include the files in the assembly and access them that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save/load files in silverlight and your app owns the files, you can use isolated storage.

[silverlight isolated storage example](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/16/tip-of-the-day-19-using-isolated-storage.aspx)

Generally, this is useful to store cross-session data locally, or store user settings. Like Josh's answer says, there is no solution to your problem if you need to access other app's files.